# Sizing Capacitors

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator

I'm sure this is a simple question for some. I have a reference circuit for a 3.3V regulator.  I would like to understand how the person who designed this circuit chose the capacitance values and why.

Furthermore, why are there two capacitors and the Vo side has the higher capacitance?

[image: reference circuit]

The Vi is 5V and Vo is 3.3V.  The current draw on 3.3V side is less than 1 ampere.

Comment: What does the datasheet of the AMS1117 tell you about using that chip and what decoupling capacitors it needs? That datasheet is here: http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf  Unfortunately it is not a very good datasheet so a designer might just do "what is commonly used" and add a 10 uF cap on both sides. *Yes but one is 100 nF*, sure that might do as well. There is no "hard science" or "complex calculation" behind this.

Comment: It depends on what is the source of 5V supply, and what is the load of 3.3V as well. There is no one generic solution. Or the design could be just done with random capacitors and almost any values that fullfill the datasheet suggestions would work.

Comment: The source is a 5V battery and the 3.3V out of the regulator goes to an optocoupler anode.  What is the general purpose of the capacitors?

Comment: Linear regulators are a bit like filters. The regulator bandwidth sets how fast it can react to changing input and output currents. 
Capacitors are sized to absorb rapid current variations (and a bit for stability of the regulator itself).

Comment: "Capacitors are a bit like filters"  this makes sense so I am filtering the input and output of the regulator?

Comment: @Feynman137 no, capacitors are like capacitors; on their own, they don't filter... Regulators are like filters. Capacitors are charge storage, and thus counteract rapid current change.

Comment: By the way, I was like "oh, this question is about a negative voltage regulator" when I saw your schematic: **always** put (GND) below, not above, your supply voltage. This is just convention, but it's really confusing if you don't adhere to that :)

Comment: There is no such thing as a 5V battery. And in general regulators need capacitors at their input and output so they operate in a stable fashion, without capacitors the output could oscillate and most circuits need stable DC for operation. I've seen a 7805 without proper capacitors providing a MCU with 1Vpp high frequency AC ripple voltage superimposed on top of 4.5V DC voltage.

Comment: So if I had a 5V regulator with Vin as 12V I would just stick the same capacitors on the circuit?  This seems strange.

Comment: I know there is no such thing as 5V battery.  I mean a battery and circuit with a 5V output.  Would a flyback diode provide similar protection?

Comment: A battery with 5V output - Are you talking about USB powerbanks? Those devices have switch mode power supplies, and therefore correct capacitor value and type is even more important. But if the datasheet says the capacitors are OK for both 3.3V and 5V regulators, then they are OK. The thing is if instead of AMS1117 you get LD1117 or LM1117 the requirements could differ.

Comment: Yea I am talking about 5V usb power bank, like used for cell phone charging.

Comment: I think having more than 10uF of capacitance on USB power input will violate USB specification. But on the other hand, the 10uF is on the output side of the regulator, so it just might limit the inrush current enough. It should still work even if it is not USB compliant, but it depends if you are going to sell this so whether you need it to be USB compliant or not.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie "There is no "hard science" or "complex calculation" behind this." Well, there should be, but it's hardly complex. Lots of application notes describe the theory of choosing input and output capacitors to keep a linear regulator stable. Hopefully, the Spice model provided captures loop stability concerns and can be used in a simulation to test performance and phase margin and compare to the prototype of the circuit.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Yes and no, Yes, the **designer(s)** of that regulator IC will have done that analysis and the result of that should be in the datasheet in the form of an **application diagram**. That application diagram should show the values that someone who uses that IC should be using. So that's the "no", the user (circuit designer using that IC) should **just follow the datasheet**. This user **cannot know** what is needed for stability and therefore should just follow the datasheet. That's the purpose of such IC's, follow the instructions and it "just works".

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica From my experience just follow recommendation on datasheet help to create finished product. For just entertainment you may play that game but sometimes it is time wasting. Somebody already invested time and shared his knowledge, why discard that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The datasheet **load regulation** error depends on the ratio of output impedance, Zo to load R ratio with negative feedback internally reducing the Zo (open loop of emitter follower or source follower in MOSFET type LDO’s ( which have lower dropout yet more critical ranges for stability on cap choices.)

The output cap ESR reduces transient step pulse voltage error further where the open-loop Zo (f) matches the impedance Xc(f) of the output cap.

Thus for a worst-case over temperature spec of 0 to 0.8A for 1.2W max loss on the SOT @ 3.3 V is 25 mV on a  3.3V/0.8A load = 4.125 Ohms

- this means the cap ESR must be less than 25mV/0.8A= 31 mOhm. Low ESR caps range in small sizes from ESR*C from 1 to 10 us typically cheap e-caps are >10x worse ( slower). Thus for a 10uF low ESR cap, you can expect  ESR’s of 100 mOhm which results in a step load overshoot or undershoot more than 3x greater than the steady-state “load regulation” error. So if your step load is much smaller in a uC, you can get away with this. But it would be worse you had some other full step load for ripple noise.

LDO’s ONLY source current and depends on the load to pull-down and the GBW is much like an Op Amp so in order to reduce Zo with feedback gain you compromise BW so an output cap is necessary unless your uC is drawing constant power all the time at 10MHz.

Similar effects are required for supply source impedance to achieve a reasonable PSRR spec and are assumed as low as the output with a time constant greater than the BW of the regulator can correct. So a smaller C is only needed with these assumptions to handle the ripple noise above 10kHz.

**Is that simple?**  yes it's basically Ohms Law and RC experience on e-caps.  However connection peak current and duration depends on V/ESR & ESR*C